# Product shipping to U.S. only?

Tags: magento2

This is for Magento 2 Enterprise Edition.

Some products can only be shipped within the United States. How can we identify those products and prevent checkout when the shipping address is international?

Note that this only applies to certain products.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,You can do this some code.**

First create a **YES/NO** product attribute `is_usa_shipping` assign  its value to YES on which products only ship at  USA.

Then  ***you need to remove your shipping methods when  a customer select Shipping address international and Cart has items***.

In this case, *create a plugin around  method on `CollectRates` of your shipping method and change the behavior.*

Suppose ,you want remove  Table rate when you cart have USA item

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\CoreRewrite\Plugin;
class TablerateForFrontPlugin
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $quoteFactory;

     public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory

    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
   }
    public function aroundCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate $subject ,
        \Closure $proceed ,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    )
    {
         foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

            $is_usa_shipping = $item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('is_usa_shipping');
            $is_usa_shipping_value = $description_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($item->getProduct());
            // If  not EQual USA  Then disabled
            if($is_usa_shipping_value && $request->getDestCountryId() !='US'):
                return false;
            endif;

         }
        return  $proceed($request);

    }

}
```

http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-how-to-disabled-free-shipping-method-in-frontend/